# Google Maps Labels and listener event driven CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API v3 along with the [MarkerWithLabel library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.0/).

I'm dropping timestamps for each lat/lon pair in labels but I want to hide them unless zoom is over 15 to prevent crowding.

My listener is firing and reporting zoom levels to console but the CSS changes are not seen.  If I issue `$('.gmapslabels').css('display', 'none');` from the console the labels are hidden immediately.

So I am guessing the maps event functions context must override `$` but I'm not clear how to get past it.

How do I set styles from inside the listener event?

**Edit** - Markers library is setting a variety of CSS every time zoom changes so probably the answer here is editing the library or locating methods the library uses to override CSS.

From my maps init():

```
 var marker2 = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lon"))),
   draggable: false,
   map: map,
   labelContent: markers[i].getAttribute("t"),
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
   labelClass: "gmapslabels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
 });

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
if(zoomLevel >= 15) {
    $('.gmapslabels').css('display', 'inline-block');
    console.log("Showing labels");  
} else {
    $('.gmapslabels').css('display', 'none');
    console.log("Hiding labels");   
}
```

Comment: Google Maps loads through XMLHttp - request, maybe you try to catch those events and override the css? var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        alert("Success callback");
    }, false); best M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library has a `labelVisible` property for marker objects.

I had to store them to an array when making them and then I can iterate over them and set visibility etc like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
if(zoomLevel >= 15) {
    for (var i = 0; i < labelsArray.length; i++ ) {
        labelsArray[i].labelVisible = true;
      }
    console.log("Showing labels");  
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < labelsArray.length; i++ ) {
        labelsArray[i].labelVisible = false;
      }
    console.log("Hiding labels");   
}
});
```